# Не загружаются локальные изображения в React

Tags: reactjs

Не могу понять, почему при указании локальных путей, картинка не загружается.
Пробовал менять высоту начала пути и начинать даже с корневой папки, но у вы только прямая ссылка... Как быть, нужно ли их импортить?

```
import React from 'react';

class Slider extends React.Component {
    constructor() { 
        super();
        this.state = {
            slideIndex:0,
            images: [ 
                '../src/Home/img/slider/slide1.png',
                'https://img5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/nbig/1/c9/winter-coffee-cup-laptop-glasses-chashka-kofe-sharf-zima-nou.jpg',
                'https://img3.goodfon.com/wallpaper/nbig/2/8c/tehnika-notebook-smartfon-kofe.jpg',
                'https://www.bestfunforall.com/freepik1/imgs/Open%20notebook%20with%20a%20cup%20of%20coffee%20Wallpapers%201.jpg'
            ],
            isCycleMode:false
        };

        this.nextSlide = this.nextSlide.bind(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось их нужно просто заимпортить, спасибо документации.